# About Hadoop's map-reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am new to Hive and Hadoop.
I have implemented a task in hive. For that I have written blocks of queries in java and I am accessing Hive using JDBC from java. (Like Stored Procedure in SQL)

Hive uses Hadoop's Mapreduce for executing each and every query. So do I need to write mapreduce job (Hadoop) for it in java. (I have this doubt because as Hive is using the Hadoop mapreduce then is there any need to implment Mapper and Reducer???)

Comment: Is your question relates to reduction the number of roundtrips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Hive is generating one or more map/reduce jobs from your SQL statements and sends them to the Hadoop cluster.

Comment: ok... But is there anything like Mapreduce code for Hive JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

No, your hive queries will translate to map reduce jobs.